# AG Grid: Pagination size selector is not showing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ag-grid

I am using AG Grid in Next JS, and I am following this documentation:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-pagination/

Once pagination is active for an AG grid, the grid should show the pagination size selector. I do see two exceptions: when paginationAutoPageSize is true, it will not show the page size selector. And, you cannot turn on the page size selector after initialization.

With that in mind, I can't figure out why the page size selector is not showing for my AG Grid.

Here is my code for rendering the AG Grid. I have tried it with paginationPageSizeSelector absent, with it set to true, and with it set to an array. None of those has worked.

Is there something here I am missing? Could something outside of this code impact the page size selector? I really appreciate your help!

```
    const paginationPageSizeSelector = useMemo(() => {
        return [200, 500, 1000];
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="h-full w-full">
            {(!isDefaultConfig || !isConfigSaved) && !!configControlsPortal && (
                <RefPortal container={configControlsPortal}>
                    {!isConfigSaved && (
                        <Button
                            disabled={configRequestStatus.pending}
                            variant="primary"
                            size="small"
                            onClick={saveTableConfig}
                        >
                            Save Column Format
                        </Button>
                    )}
                    <Button
                        disabled={configRequestStatus.pending}
                        variant="tertiary"
                        size="small"
                        onClick={resetTableConfig}
                    >
                        Restore Default
                    </Button>
                </RefPortal>
            )}
            <AgGridReact<Foo>
                ref={gridRef}
                sideBar={SIDE_BAR}
                animateRows={true}
                rowData={rows}
                gridOptions={GRID_OPTIONS}
                className="ag-theme-foo"
                defaultColDef={DEFAULT_COL_DEF}
                onFilterChanged={onFilterChanged}
                excelStyles={EXCEL_EXPORT_FORMATS}
                rowClass="cursor-pointer"
                columnDefs={autoGeneratedColumnDefs}
                onPaginationChanged={newData}
                suppressScrollOnNewData={true}
                paginationAutoPageSize={false}
                pagination={true}
                paginationPageSize={100}
                paginationPageSizeSelector={paginationPageSizeSelector}
                onRowClicked={e =>
                    router.push(
                        `/shipments/${encodeURIComponent(`${e.data?.fooId}`)}`
                    )
                }
                {...gridProps}
            />
```

I tried setting the paginationPageSizeSelector to true, setting it to an array, and leaving it out. In all cases, the pagination will show, but not the pagination size selector.

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dZna.png)

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. I'm facing this error paginationPageSizeSelector  does not exist on AgGrid

Comment: I resolved this issue by updating AG Grid. Are you on the latest version?